# Intuitive understanding behind clamping of B-splines

Tags: intuition, spline

I have been going through the implementation of B-splines, and I observe that whenever it comes to clamping, it's usually mentioned that we must repeat the end knots $p+1$ times for a spline of degree $p$. However, without a very clear explanation.

Going a little further, it can be attributed to the derivative being 0, but that also seems like a result rather than cause. I have also seen that splines can be considered internal to the convex hull, and all the points being identical cause it to tangentially start from it.

I am referring to this resource quite often - [MTU Course Notes](https://pages.mtu.edu/%7Eshene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/spline/B-spline/bspline-curve-open.html)

[image: Knot Multiplicity]

Could you suggest a more intuitive or visual understanding for the clamping process?

Comment: Good question …

Comment: You’re confusing repeated knots with repeated control points. Both give us clamping/interpolation, but repeating knots is the technique that’s normally used.